# How can I format all td elements contained in a table with class myclass in CSS?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How can I format all td elements contained in a table with class myclass in CSS?

I want a format rule which applies to `<table class="myclass"><td>FORMAT THIS</td></table>.`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators) (represented by a space character):

```
table.myclass td { — }
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't this simple css will do it?

```
.myclass td{}
```

Comment: it does, however if myclass is added to any other parent element (e.g. a div) the td's will be styled. e.g. `<div class="myclass"><table class="blueBorderOnCells"><tr><td>Example</td></tr></table></div>` Example would be styled with a "blue border" AND all styling in myclass.

Answer (score 5):

```
 table.myclass td { color: blue }
```

Your table is missing a `tr` element by the way.

Answer (score 3):

as far as i am aware you would do this

```
table.myclass td { styles in here }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
table.myclass td { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

...........

```
table.myclass td{
 /* your styles */
}
```

**[Have a look at CSS selectors for more info.](http://www.cssbasics.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to know different ways to use CSS combinators.

**1.Descendant Selector (space):**
Matches all elements that are descendants of a specified element.

The following example selects all  elements inside  elements with .myclass class.

```css
table.myclass td {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**2.Child Selector (>):**
Selects all elements that are children of a specified element.

The following example selects all  elements that are children of a  element with .myclass class.

```css
table.myclass > td {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Please take a look at [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`table#myid td { color: blue }` *//each td in an individual table with id myid*

table could be dropped but i kept it for semantics.

`#myid.myclass td { color: blue }`  *//each td in anything with an id of myid and class of myclass.  <sup>"is an" id(myid)   that  "has a" class(myclass)</sup>    ;-)  *

---

<sup>things become fun especially when one starts playing with nth-child(x) etc inside "tables"!</sup>

the issue seems to be more a case of **"Scope"** than actualy assigning any css.
By assigning an **id** you **limit** .ie control the **scope** to an unique element, use **class** when you intend to **extend scope** to all elements sharing a class.
So theoretically you only need to specify the .myclass td{ etc }  , however i just wanted to affirm your intentions and reasoning, happy coding.

But yes i agree, please have a look at css selectors, and jquery(
[Sizzle](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). 
It's easy and so ..... powerful.   :X

[CSS Selectors - INCLUDING THE CSS VERSION EACH NEEDS!](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)